# .saveAsTable stopping sparkContext

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-databricks

When running a program, I am trying to save a spark df as a delta table. However, I am running into an error where the sparkContext is stopped when I use .saveAsTable. I am running a for loop to run multiple queries and write them to delta tables, but there is a specific query that doesn't like to be converted to the delta table. Here is the error:

```
An error occurred while calling o4168.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

#lots of at statements

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.SparkEntries.sc(SparkEntries.java:52)
org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.SparkEntries.sparkSession(SparkEntries.java:66)
org.apache.livy.repl.AbstractSparkInterpreter.postStart(AbstractSparkInterpreter.scala:144)
org.apache.livy.repl.SparkInterpreter.$anonfun$start$1(SparkInterpreter.scala:138)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
org.apache.livy.repl.AbstractSparkInterpreter.restoreContextClassLoader(AbstractSparkInterpreter.scala:495)
org.apache.livy.repl.SparkInterpreter.start(SparkInterpreter.scala:113)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$start$1(Session.scala:283)
scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The currently active sparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.SparkEntries.sc(SparkEntries.java:52)
org.apache.livy.rsc.driver.SparkEntries.sparkSession(SparkEntries.java:66)
org.apache.livy.repl.AbstractSparkInterpreter.postStart(AbstractSparkInterpreter.scala:144)
org.apache.livy.repl.SparkInterpreter.$anonfun$start$1(SparkInterpreter.scala:138)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
org.apache.livy.repl.AbstractSparkInterpreter.restoreContextClassLoader(AbstractSparkInterpreter.scala:495)
org.apache.livy.repl.SparkInterpreter.start(SparkInterpreter.scala:113)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$start$1(Session.scala:283)
scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

         #more at statements
```

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE: Here is my save statement:

```
spark_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable(tablename)
```

Error is at .saveAsTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, switched the troubled query to a new notebook and ran just fine. Odd!

Answer (score 0):

By using the .saveAsTable() function, you can save the results of your data analysis or processing tasks in a structured manner, enabling you to query and analyze the data efficiently in the future. This can be particularly useful when working with large datasets or when collaborating with others on data analysis projects.

Comment: I am already using .saveAsTable, I added my save statement in an edit